# VBA code for excel. 3D Rotation

Tags: excel, 3d, vba

I'm coming back with an old question for which I got an answer from you. 
The old question can be found following this link:

[VBA Code for excel. How to create graphs in separated sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469241/vba-code-for-excel-how-to-create-graphs-in-separated-sheets#)

I have did some modification for my requirements, but I need some help regarding 3D plots.  Exactly, I want to have the following settings

[image]

The VBA code is:

```
Sub Linearity_Plot()

Dim pas As Integer, val As Integer, lCol As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, ch As Chart

With Sheets("HOOD")
    lCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    val = .Range("A1").Value
    pas = val + 2
     Rows("2:4").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("A2").Select
Selection.ClearContents  
For j = 2 To lCol
Cells(2, j).Value = Left(Right(Left(Cells(1, j), 17), 5), 2)
Next

    ' insert an empty column and a copy of column A
    For colx = pas To lCol Step pas
        .Columns(colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Columns(colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Columns(1).Copy .Columns(colx + 1)
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' for every group of columns generate a chart and move it to end of Workbook
    lCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = -1 To lCol - 1 Step pas
        Set ch = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add '<~~ add a chart in own new sheet
        ch.ChartType = xl3DArea
        ch.SetSourceData .Range(.Cells(2, i + 2), .Cells(251, i + pas))
        ch.Name = "Chart" & CInt(1 + (i + 2) / pas)
        ch.Move , ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        Next

End With

End Sub
```

I have tried to record a macro and to put the new code after

```
lCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = -1 To lCol - 1 Step pas
    Set ch = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add '<~~ add a chart in own new sheet
    ch.ChartType = xl3DArea
    ch.SetSourceData .Range(.Cells(2, i + 2), .Cells(251, i + pas))
    ch.Name = "Chart" & CInt(1 + (i + 2) / pas)
    ch.Move , ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    Next
```

but I did not manage to obtain something.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Returns a ThreeDFormat object that contains the three-dimensional effect formatting properties of the specified chart, and is read-only.(in excell help)

Comment: I thik it is not possible. TreeDformat is read-only.

Comment: Is there any other chance to do that?

Comment: I tested but it is impossible. I think it is not supported in vba. That's how it's written in Excel Help.